# Отображение на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем Привет, столкнулся с проблемой отображения модального окна, т.е Модалка открывается в режиме адаптивного дизайна и срабатывает на Firefox на всех симулируемых девайсах. а по факту на андроид и Ios никак( в живую) (((

HTML

```
 <a class="btn btn-info"   data-toggle="adaptive-modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLoginModal();">   Войти  </a>
```

JS

```
    function openLoginModal(){
    showLoginForm();
    setTimeout(function(){

        $('#loginModal').modal('show'); 

    }, 230);

}

function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');    
        });

        $('.modal-title').html('Войти');
    });       
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html(''); 
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в стилях. Привидет воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Сложно сказать что не так, но в качестве варианта предлагаю использовать отладку мобильной верстки на телефоне с использованием Google Chrome через инструмент remote device. [Ссылка на оригинал](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), на русском языке не нашел, но может быть это сможет помочь в изучении  проблемы.

Comment: Действительно Хром начал ругаться сразу ..Uncaught ReferenceError: openLoginModal is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: openLoginModal те не видит функцию?

Comment: openLoginModal как её обьявить?

Comment: В общем все заработало, в хроме ошибка в js висела и не давала запустить код, хотя firefox проглотил